# Safari does not appear the image on my site

Tags: html, ios, iphone, macos, safari

i don't know what i missing here but it fails to appear entirely in iPhones i think in Safari too. It shows perfectly in Chrome & Edge

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div class="container">
  <a href = "https://www.rodoscars.info/?api=casacook"</a>        
  <img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1gEAfmXqpA35AhxhtrIv4lIQphGJ7eTt8" class="img-thumbnail" alt="RODOS CARS" width="304" height="236">
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `class="img-thumbnail"` does styling applied on this class

Comment: Download google drive image and use src with image file extension eg. .jpg .png .gif .svg

Comment: @UmeshShejole thanks for your response but i don't think that is possible with google drive, or i can't find it

Comment: @JovylleBermudez thanks for your response, the problem continuous

Comment: @AlanTurist my mistake my question was not complete. I mean. Does that class have styling?

Comment: @JovylleBermudez yes

Comment: Please can you show us. That must be included in your post or at least any more helpful details

Comment: @JovylleBermudez i would like to embedded that code on google site. It must appears an image button that redirect you in an other site. That works everywhere except safari

Comment: @JovylleBermudez check here

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GG8EVWHGZR98

Comment: I found it, <div class="container"> must be <div>

Thanks for your answers!